# How to download images, convert them to a single PDF and store it encrypted on disk BUFFERED?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, pdf, encryption

I want to download a document via web service. The web service returns every page as an image (to be more precise: a URL to an image) (this flow can't be changed).

After executing this service I have an array of URLs to images. I want to download them, after downloading I want to convert them to PDF and after converting I want to store the PDF on disk, encrypted (AES).

Each of this tasks is not that complicated, but I want it memory efficient (i. e. buffered).

My desired workflow:

1. For each URL
2. Download the data
3. Convert that data to a PDF page
4. Encrypt that page
5. Append it to some file on the disk

Is this possible? If yes, how?

**Hope anyone still reads this**

My idea:

1. Subclass NSMutableData. (I would name it NSPersistentData)
2. Override [appendBytes:]. Each time bytes
   should be appended, encrypt them and store them on disk instead.
3. Pass that subclass to UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData.

Comment: If buffering is the main problem, you might consider changing the title of your question.

Comment: Why subclass NSMutableData instead of just encrypt your data like normal?

Comment: Once again: It has to be buffered.. I can't hold a 50 MB PDF in memory, then encrypt it (I guess this will create at least another 50 MB) and then write it on disk.

Comment: I get that, I thought you were proposing doing the downloading and encryption per image.

Comment: well I guess that's not possible.. I can't encrypt the image and then convert it to a PDF page, it has to be the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

**Download Image**

You can download image using [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFContext/Reference/reference.html) or some open source code !!!

**Convert to PDF**

For this you can create a [CGPDFContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFContext/Reference/reference.html), draw your UIImage into it, and save it to a file.

Once you are done with that apply some encryption technique to the file & save it to disk.

Hope this Helps !!!